# Printing several graphs from a loop on one page over several pages

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I have a bunch of individual plots for subjects that I'd like to include in appendix.This is just one example of over 1000 plots I have to produce. Ideally I'd like to print 6 plots per page and export them as jpeg to include.

I'm trying to print 6 plots per page, but the

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 2))
```

command is not working, I still get only one plot per page. I was hoping someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong please.
Code below.

```
Subjects <- unique(data2$Subject)

par(mfrow = c(3, 2))

for (i in seq_along(Subjects)) {
  plot <- ggplot(data=subset(data2, data2$Subject==Subjects[i]), 
                 aes(x=Actual.Time, y=Concentration, group=Formulation, 
                     colour=Formulation)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = Formulation), lwd=0.7) +
    geom_point(aes(group = Formulation), lwd=2) +
    ggtitle(sprintf("Subject %s", Subjects[i])) +
    labs(x="Actual time (h)", y="Concentration (ng/mL)") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black","blue"))
  print(plot)
}
```

Comment: Try using the cowplot or patchwork package.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a solution using `ggplot2::facet_wrap()` to create 6 plots per page, within a loop to make a separate faceted plot for each page:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tables <- unique(diamonds$table)
pages <- list()
n_per <- 6
n_pages <- 2

for (i in 1:n_pages) {
  pages[[i]] <- diamonds %>%
    filter(table %in% tables[(i * n_per - n_per + 1):(i * n_per)]) %>%
    ggplot(aes(carat, price)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(vars(table), ncol = 2)
}

pages
```

[image]

[image]